# How could I protect the users from my webpage from being tracked?

Tags: security, analytics, tracking, privacy, anonymous

This is maybe quite a broad question and I tried to look for other stack exchanges where addressing my question would suit better – but in the end I decided that it might be still a question of a technical nature, and so I am posting it here:

I recently started to think more about **privacy** and **security** and I realized that I as a web user can only do so much about staying untracked. VPN, (slow) Tor, privacy helpers, add-blockers, Firefox are just a few tools to name, but still I realize that the information that I normally share (like installed add-ons, browser size, IP location etc.) can still very well be fingerprinted.

Normally as a web-developer I am told that we should add analytics, that we should find out more about the users to «make a better service», but I think I would like to do the opposite.

So:
**Are there steps I could take, when building a website, that help the visitors to stay untracked?** And I don't mean «not installing google analytics», I mean things like somehow actively messing with the statistics, so that my hosters server is incapable of tracking things correctly or similar things...
Right now I can't really think of anything, but I somehow believe that I as a person who builds bricks of the internet could and should be able to influence these kind of things directly...

For now I see the obvious things:
- not using statistic services
- use https
- not using any third party tools that might include tracking or open doors for other trackers
But still this seems to just omit the bad things, but I can't actually do active stuff...

So I would be very glad to hear your thoughts about this. (Or guide me to a place, where this discussion fits a better..)

Cheers

merc

Answer (score 1):

As a web developer, you can only control your website.

Assuming you aren't caching any data or using cookies, then users shouldn't be tracked while using your website by tools like 3rd party cookies.

Here is a [good article about online tracking and how it works.](https://robertheaton.com/2017/11/20/how-does-online-tracking-actually-work/)

As far as I know, there isn't an effective way to actively mess with tracking statistics. Your best bet is to avoid installing libraries or tools that track your users.

Comment: Thx by the way for your comment. Sad story, we as contributors to the web can't really do anything...